# 'SetPasswordForm' object has no attribute ‘save’ - Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

I am trying to setup the `SetPasswordForm` on Django, but I get the following error when trying to put in a new password: `'SetPasswordForm' object has no attribute ‘save’`.

Would anyone know how to configure this properly? Thank you in advance!

***forms.py:***

```
class SetPasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='New password',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                                    attrs={'placeholder': 'New password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Verify',
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                                    attrs={'placeholder': 'Password again'}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(SetPasswordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password_length = settings.MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        if len(password1) < password_length:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Password must be longer than "
                "{} characters".format(password_length))
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2:
            if password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
        return password2
```

***views.py:***

```
@sensitive_post_parameters()
@never_cache
def password_reset_confirm(request, uidb64=None, token=None,
                           token_generator=default_token_generator):
    assert uidb64 is not None and token is not None
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = MyUser._default_manager.get(pk=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, MyUser.DoesNotExist):
        user = None

    if user is not None and token_generator.check_token(user, token):
        validlink = True
        form = SetPasswordForm(request.POST or None, user=user)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()  # Error traces back to here
                return HttpResponseRedirect(render("login"))
    else:
        validlink = False
        form = None
        messages.error(request, "Password reset unsuccessful")
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'validlink': validlink
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/settings/password_set.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to add the following to my form:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    self.user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password2'])
    if commit:
        self.user.save()
    return self.user
```